# Pandas - create new column with the sum of last N values of another column

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
       round_id          team       opponent  home_dummy   GC   GP  P
0          1.0       Flamengo    Atlético-MG         1.0  1.0  0.0  0
1          4.0       Flamengo         Grêmio         1.0  1.0  1.0  1
2          5.0       Flamengo       Botafogo         1.0  1.0  1.0  1
3          6.0       Flamengo         Santos         0.0  0.0  1.0  3
4          7.0       Flamengo          Bahia         0.0  3.0  5.0  3
5          8.0       Flamengo      Fortaleza         1.0  1.0  2.0  3
6          9.0       Flamengo     Fluminense         0.0  1.0  2.0  3
7         10.0       Flamengo          Ceará         0.0  2.0  0.0  0
8          3.0       Flamengo       Coritiba         0.0  0.0  1.0  3
9         11.0       Flamengo          Goiás         1.0  1.0  2.0  3
10        13.0       Flamengo   Athlético-PR         1.0  1.0  3.0  3
11        14.0       Flamengo          Sport         1.0  0.0  3.0  3
12        15.0       Flamengo          Vasco         0.0  1.0  2.0  3
13        16.0       Flamengo     Bragantino         1.0  1.0  1.0  1
14        17.0       Flamengo    Corinthians         0.0  1.0  5.0  3
15        18.0       Flamengo  Internacional         0.0  2.0  2.0  1
16        19.0       Flamengo      São Paulo         1.0  4.0  1.0  0
17        12.0       Flamengo      Palmeiras         0.0  1.0  1.0  1
18         2.0       Flamengo    Atlético-GO         0.0  3.0  0.0  0
19        20.0       Flamengo    Atlético-MG         0.0  4.0  0.0  0
```

---

Now I'd like to add a column 'last_5', which consists of the sum of the last 5 'P' values, ending up with:

```
     rodada_id          clube       opponent  home_dummy   GC   GP  P  last_5
0          1.0       Flamengo    Atlético-MG         1.0  1.0  0.0  0  0
1          4.0       Flamengo         Grêmio         1.0  1.0  1.0  1  0
2          5.0       Flamengo       Botafogo         1.0  1.0  1.0  1  1
3          6.0       Flamengo         Santos         0.0  0.0  1.0  3  2
4          7.0       Flamengo          Bahia         0.0  3.0  5.0  3  5
5          8.0       Flamengo      Fortaleza         1.0  1.0  2.0  3  8
6          9.0       Flamengo     Fluminense         0.0  1.0  2.0  3 11
7         10.0       Flamengo          Ceará         0.0  2.0  0.0  0 13
8          3.0       Flamengo       Coritiba         0.0  0.0  1.0  3 12
9         11.0       Flamengo          Goiás         1.0  1.0  2.0  3 12
10        13.0       Flamengo   Athlético-PR         1.0  1.0  3.0  3 12
11        14.0       Flamengo          Sport         1.0  0.0  3.0  3 12
12        15.0       Flamengo          Vasco         0.0  1.0  2.0  3 12
13        16.0       Flamengo     Bragantino         1.0  1.0  1.0  1 15
14        17.0       Flamengo    Corinthians         0.0  1.0  5.0  3 13
15        18.0       Flamengo  Internacional         0.0  2.0  2.0  1 11
16        19.0       Flamengo      São Paulo         1.0  4.0  1.0  0  8
17        12.0       Flamengo      Palmeiras         0.0  1.0  1.0  1  8
18         2.0       Flamengo    Atlético-GO         0.0  3.0  0.0  0  6
19        20.0       Flamengo    Atlético-MG         0.0  4.0  0.0  0  5
```

Please note that up to index 4 (n=5), the sum will have to be of the last 1, 2, 3, 4 rows.

I have tried:

```
N = 5

df = df.groupby(df.P // N).sum()
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['Last_5'] = df.P.rolling(5,min_periods=1).sum().shift().fillna(0)

Out[9]: 
0      0.0
1      0.0
2      1.0
3      2.0
4      5.0
5      8.0
6     11.0
7     13.0
8     12.0
9     12.0
10    12.0
11    12.0
12    12.0
13    15.0
14    13.0
15    13.0
16    11.0
17     8.0
18     6.0
19     5.0
```

Comment: that was fast, Ben. could you please expand your answer so as to add this new series to the previous one, for completeness sake?

Comment: @8-BitBorges you mean assign it back ~ :-)

Comment: You don't need `.fillna(0)` if you first do the `.shift()` and then choose `min_periods=0`: `df['Last_5'] = df['P'].shift().rolling(5, min_periods=0).sum()`