# Pandas new column that is sum of last N columns

Tags: pandas

Using Python 3.7 & Pandas, how can I create a new column that is the sum of the last N columns?
There are several questions with this title (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812644/pandas-create-new-column-with-the-sum-of-last-n-values-of-another-column)), but they all seem to be referring to rolling thru last N *rows* which is not what I am after

```
col1 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
col2 = [1,5,9,2,4,2,5,6,1]
col3 = [25,14,2,15,18,98,65,4,77]
col4 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2, col3, col4)), columns =['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

**Desired Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
c = df.columns
df['last_2'] = df.loc[:,c[-2:]].sum(1)
#df['last_3'] = df.loc[:,c[-3:]].sum(1)

0    26
1    15
2     3
3    16
4    19
5    99
6    66
7     5
8    78
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You could use iloc directly to access the last n columns: `df.iloc[:, -2:].sum(1)`